# ASP.Net MVC WEB API - JSON - auto add API version to generated JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, formatting

I have developed an ASP.NET WEB API that generates JSON data to be consumed by some other party. Now I have received a request for adding some extra data in each JSON response about the version of the WEB API.

Is there a simple way to extend the built-in JSON formatter so it will auto-append/prepend some fixed JSON properties whenever it formats some data-model or a collection of some data-model?

Thanks for any good advice :-)

Comment: You're returning JsonResult from your API?

Comment: Requirement has been dropped.